# Some contract functions runs on hardhat network While others don't

Tags: solidity, chai, hardhat

I Got following error while testing my contract

```bash
$ npx hardhat test


  NftyplayLicense
    buyLicense
done!
      1) should buy the license successfully


  0 passing (2s)
  1 failing

  1) NftyplayLicense
       buyLicense
         should buy the license successfully:
     Error: invalid address or ENS name (argument="name", value=undefined, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.7.0)
      at Logger.makeError (node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:269:28)
      at Logger.throwError (node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:281:20)
      at Logger.throwArgumentError (node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:285:21)
      at /home/bhavesh/Documents/boilerplate/node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/src.ts/index.ts:123:16
      at step (node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/lib/index.js:48:23)
      at Object.next (node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/lib/index.js:29:53)
      at fulfilled (node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/lib/index.js:20:58)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Following is the Test that I have written

```js
const { assert, expect } = require("chai")
const { network, ethers, deployments } = require("hardhat")
const { developmentChains } = require("../helper-hardhat-config")

!developmentChains.includes(network.name)
    ? describe.skip()
    : describe("NftyplayLicense", function () {
          let nftyplayLicenseContract, nftyPlayLicense, deployer, player, param

          beforeEach(async function () {
              const accounts = await ethers.getSigners()
              deployer = accounts[0]
              player = accounts[1]
              await deployments.fixture(["all"])

              nftyplayLicenseContract = await ethers.getContract("NftyPlayLicensing")
              nftyPlayLicense = nftyplayLicenseContract.connect(deployer)

              param = {
                  name: "NftyPlayLicensing",
                  category: "1",
                  durationInDays: "1",
                  licenseType: "1",
                  nftAddress: "0x3C44CdDdB6a900fa2b585dd299e03d12FA4293BC",
                  nonce: 735,
                  price: "1000000000000000000",
                  r: "0xb07df588e0674bc28050a58a7f2cfd315f7e0aec136d0ebcf89fdcd9fa8aa928",
                  s: "0x109a8b6ff70709d2fecdba8b385097f2f979738518e4c444d4cf95b7e2c9621b",
                  signer: "0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266",
                  tokenId: "1",
                  v: 27,
              }
          })
          describe("buyLicense", function () {
              it("should buy the license successfully", async function () {
                  nftyPlayLicense.whitelist("0x3C44CdDdB6a900fa2b585dd299e03d12FA4293BC")
                  console.log("done!")
                  nftyPlayLicense = nftyplayLicenseContract.connect(player)
                  await expect(
                      nftyPlayLicense.buyLicense(param, "https://uri.com", {
                          value: ethers.utils.parseEther("1"),
                      })
                  ).to.emit("NftyPlayLicensing", "LicenseBought")
                  const result = await nftyPlayLicense.getExecutedOrder(735)

                  assert.equal(result, true)
              })
          })
      })
```

Note that

```js
  nftyPlayLicense.whitelist("0x3C44CdDdB6a900fa2b585dd299e03d12FA4293BC")
```

is running fine, not not in case of

```js
 nftyPlayLicense.buyLicense(param, "https://uri.com", {
                          value: ethers.utils.parseEther("1"),
                      })
```

I've made order and signature object by metamask and stored it locally and then using that i am calling buyLicense function from contract using that object as params.

this is my contract function:

```
function buyLicense(OrderTypes.LicenseOrder calldata order, string memory uri) public payable {
        require(isOrderExecuted[order.nonce] == false, "Order is already Executed");
        require(isCancelled[order.signer][order.nonce] == false, "Listing is Cancelled");
        bytes32 orderHash = SignatureVerifier.hashMakerOrder(order, ORDER_TYPE_HASH);
        validateMakerOrder(order, orderHash);
        uint256 licenseTokenId = mintLicenseToken(msg.sender, uri, order);

        isOrderExecuted[order.nonce] = true;

        emit LicenseBought(
            licenseTokenId,
            order.price,
            order.category,
            order.tokenId,
            order.signer,
            order.licenseType,
            order.nftContract
        );
    }
```

But I am unable to run that function

Comment: Please share the code snippet for `OrderTypes ` as well

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.